# Cannot install Nvidia Driver on Ubunutu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, 18.04, dpkg

Hello I am trying to install the official nvidia driver for my Ubuntu 18.04.The error I get is :

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-390 : Depends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After I run `apt --fix-broken install` as said , and gives me:

```
(Reading database ... 194729 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.67-0ubuntu0
```

I have tried purge, clean install and none of these work.

Comment: Please look at this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072999/nvidia-driver-problem-after-apt-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04